# I want my board to be printed as a rhombus. So every previous line should have a smaller indentation than the next. How can I do that?

Tags: python

```
global counter
global winner
def initBoard():
    global x
    global y
    x = int(input("Give x size for the board "))
    while x < 1 or x > 20:
        x = int(input("Please give a valid input (between 1 and 20) "))
    y = int(input("Give y size for the board "))
    while y < 1 or y > 20:
        y = int(input("Please give a valid input (between 1 and 20) "))
    i = 0
    j = 0
    global board
    board = [[0 for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]

def showBoard():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(1,1 + y):
        for j in range(1,1 + x):
            if j % x == 0:
                print("[", board [i-1] [j-1], "]", "\n")
            else:
                print("[", board [i-1] [j-1], "]", end="")

def setPiece():
    return 0

def play():
    initBoard()
    showBoard()

play()
```

My code so far. Haven't completed the setPiece function so don't stress about that. Function initBoard asks for user dimensions and initialises the board and the function showBoard is supposed to print the board. It does print it but I don't know how to print it like described on the title

Comment: Your code example does not work on its own. Please provide a [minimal and complete working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies. Now it should be fine

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
global counter
global winner


def initBoard():
    global x
    global y
    x = int(input("Give x size for the board "))
    while x < 1 or x > 20:
        x = int(input("Please give a valid input (between 1 and 20) "))
    y = int(input("Give y size for the board "))
    while y < 1 or y > 20:
        y = int(input("Please give a valid input (between 1 and 20) "))

    global board
    board = [[0 for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]


def showBoard():
    for i in range(1, 1 + y):
        for j in range(1, 1 + x):
            if j % x == 0:
                print("[", board[i-1][j-1], "]", "\n")
                print(" " * i*3, end="")   # write a space depending on the row without line break
            else:
                print("[", board[i-1][j-1], "]", end="")


def setPiece():
    return 0


def play():
    initBoard()
    showBoard()

play()
```

I used `end=""` to prevent the line break after the print statement that sets a number of spaces depending on which line you are in. By changing the factor `i*3` to something else, you can adjust the slope. Ah, and I fixed the formatting. Be sure to read the [PEP 8 style guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to achieve readable and consistent code formatting.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!